# Add means to a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add the mean values to my basic boxplot and found this function here.

```
fun_mean <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)))
}
```

I used it within my code, but because I have two factors, it is not working properly. Where do I have to add the second factor?

```
FixationT2.plot = ggplot(dataT2fix_figs, 
                         aes(x = length, y = perc_fixated, fill = mask)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_cartesian (ylim =c(35, 100)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 50) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", colour="darkred", size=3) +
  labs(title="") +
  xlab("Länge Wort N+1") +   
  ylab("Fixationswahrscheinlichkeit in %\n von Wort N+1") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Preview Maske"))
```

[image: current boxplot]

This is what the data looks like

```
 Subject length         mask                  perc_fixated
<fct>   <fct>          <fct>                        <dbl>
1 1       "kurzes\n N+1" keine Maske                   41.7
2 1       "kurzes\n N+1" syntaktisch korrekt           91.7
3 1       "kurzes\n N+1" syntaktisch inkorrekt         86.7
4 1       "langes \nN+1" keine Maske                  100  
5 1       "langes \nN+1" syntaktisch korrekt           87.5
6 1       "langes \nN+1" syntaktisch inkorrekt         91.7
7 2       "kurzes\n N+1" keine Maske                   73.3
8 2       "kurzes\n N+1" syntaktisch korrekt           84.6
9 2       "kurzes\n N+1" syntaktisch inkorrekt         83.3
10 2       "langes \nN+1" keine Maske                   83.3
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data? If you cannot provide a representative sample of `dataT2fix_figs`, then perhaps switch to a well-known dataset such as `iris` or `mtcars`.

Comment: your `stat_summary` probably needs `group`. If you provide your data using `dput` it's easy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the dodge width for the calculated mean value layer. Right now they appear to be overlapping one another at each x-axis value. I don't see the function you mentioned (`fun_mean`) actually used in the ggplot code, but it shouldn't really be necessary.

Try this:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = length, y = perc_fixated, fill = mask)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", colour="darkred", size=3,
               position = position_dodge2(width = 0.75))
# ... code for axis titles & so on omitted for brevity.
```

I used `width = 0.75` above, because this is the default width for `geom_boxplot()` / `stat_boxplot()` (as found in the ggplot2 code [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/3fc9309a757a67517c262151dfb13363214f1112/R/stat-boxplot.r)). If you specify a width explicitly in your boxplot, use that instead.

[image: plot]

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE,
                 text = 'Subject length         mask                  perc_fixated
                 1 1       "kurzes\n N+1" "keine Maske"                   41.7
                 2 1       "kurzes\n N+1" "syntaktisch korrekt"           91.7
                 3 1       "kurzes\n N+1" "syntaktisch inkorrekt"         86.7
                 4 1       "langes \nN+1" "keine Maske"                  100  
                 5 1       "langes \nN+1" "syntaktisch korrekt"           87.5
                 6 1       "langes \nN+1" "syntaktisch inkorrekt"         91.7
                 7 2       "kurzes\n N+1" "keine Maske"                   73.3
                 8 2       "kurzes\n N+1" "syntaktisch korrekt"           84.6
                 9 2       "kurzes\n N+1" "syntaktisch inkorrekt"         83.3
                 10 2       "langes \nN+1" "keine Maske"                   83.3')
df$Subject <- factor(df$Subject)
```

(Next time, please use `dput()` as advised in the comments to provide your data.)

Answer (score 0):

I have in the past just used the `points()` function to add mean to my box plots like this:

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl)
points(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
       y = tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, "mean"), col = "red")
```

So you plot a boxplot then calculate the mean for each of your boxes and plot them as the `y` argument in `points` and the `x` is just a sequence with length how ever many boxes you have.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. I tried it like this but now all the points disappeared without any error message.  points(x= c (1,2,3,4,5,6),
           y= tapply(dataT2fix_figs$perc_fixated,list(dataT2fix_figs$length, dataT2fix_figs$mask), "mean"), col="red")+

Comment: what do you get back from this? : `tapply(dataT2fix_figs$perc_fixated,list(dataT2fix_figs$length, dataT2fix_figs$mask), "mean")` You are expecting a vector of 6 numbers

Comment: Yes, this is working, I get a vector with the right means. I think the x values are not working

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I'm not sure what ggplot wants here. I'm more comfortable with base plotting functions for boxplots. Perhaps you should use the answer given by @z-lin